# How can I update a popup while shown?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, properties, operator

I'd like to display a *popup*, that shows some custom properties. Which properties are drawn or enabled depends on the settings of some other properties of this *popup*. The *popup* is invoked by [`context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html?highlight=invoke_props_dialog#bpy.types.WindowManager.invoke_props_dialog).

Here's a small example (properties are coming from the addon-preferences):

```
box = layout.box()
if not( up and up.preferences.simplify_ui):
    box.prop(up.preferences, "simplify_ui")

if up and up.preferences.simplify_ui:
    row = box.row()
    row.prop(prefs, "simplify_ui")

    row.prop(prefs, "auto_simplify_ui")

    #...
```

How can I update the popup?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like written in my comment i've written a workaround. The old popup is closed after short delay by a simulated press of the ESC-key. After a second short delay the cursor is placed on the position it was on the initial invoke of the popup. Then the popup is reopened after a third delay. Finally the cursorposition is restored after an last delay. Each delay takes 0.01 seconds.

Here's the code of the workaround (**init**.py):

```
import sys
if   sys.platform == 'linux' :
    from .lib import fake_input_x11 as fake_input
elif sys.platform == 'win32' :
    from .lib import fake_input_win as fake_input
elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
    from .lib import fake_input_mac as fake_input
else:
    from .lib import fake_input_x11 as fake_input

bpy.props.simple_edit_prefs_popup_shown  = False
bpy.props.simple_edit_prefs_popup_redraw = False

#....

class simple_edit_preferences(bpy.types.AddonPreferences):

    #....

    def update_prefs_popup(self, context):
        self.update_prefs(context)

        update_popup(self, context)

#....

def update_popup(self, context):
    if bpy.props.simple_edit_prefs_popup_shown and fake_input.usable:
        bpy.props.simple_edit_prefs_popup_redraw = True

        new_pos = fake_input.position()

        t = [time.time()]
        i = [0]

        handles = bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post

        @bpy.app.handlers.persistent
        def on_scene_update(scene):
            if time.time()-t[0] > 0.01:
                t[0] = time.time()
                i[0] = i[0] + 1

                if   i[0]==1:
                    fake_input.esc()
                elif i[0]==2:
                    old_pos = bpy.props.simple_edit_prefs_popup_pos
                    fake_input.moveTo(old_pos[0], old_pos[1])
                elif i[0]==3:
                    bpy.ops.ui.simple_edit_simplify_ui_popup("INVOKE_DEFAULT")
                elif i[0]==4:
                    fake_input.moveTo(new_pos[0], new_pos[1])
                    bpy.props.simple_edit_prefs_popup_redraw = False

                    handles.remove(on_scene_update)

        handles.append(on_scene_update)


class UI_OT_simple_edit_simplify_ui_popup(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Simplify User Interface Popup"""
    bl_idname = "ui.simple_edit_simplify_ui_popup"
    bl_label = "Simplify User Interface"
    bl_description = "Show popup to simplify the user interface by removing areas, menu entries and other elements of the user interface"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}


    def execute(self, context):
        if not bpy.props.simple_edit_prefs_popup_redraw:
            bpy.props.simple_edit_prefs_popup_shown = False
            bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        bpy.props.simple_edit_prefs_popup_shown = True
        bpy.props.simple_edit_prefs_popup_self  = self
        bpy.props.simple_edit_prefs_popup_pos   = fake_input.position()

        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self, width=600)

    def draw(self, context):
        simple_edit_preferences.draw_menus(self.layout, context)
```

update_prefs_popup is called on each update of the relevant properties.

fake_input_x11.py:

```
@property
def usable():
    return True

import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib import X
from Xlib.ext.xtest import fake_input
from Xlib import XK

__display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])

def position():
    pos = __display.screen().root.query_pointer()._data
    return pos["root_x"], pos["root_y"]

def moveTo(x, y):
    fake_input(__display, X.MotionNotify, x=x, y=y)
    __display.sync()

def keyDown(key):
    fake_input(__display, X.KeyPress, key)
    __display.sync()

def keyUp(key):
    fake_input(__display, X.KeyRelease, key)
    __display.sync()

def esc():
    key = __display.keysym_to_keycode(XK.string_to_keysym('Escape'))
    keyDown(key)
    keyUp  (key)
```

I've downloaded Xlib and added it to the lib-folder of the addon. The path of this folder has to be published in sys.path cause some modules of Xlib are doing something like `import Xlib`.

Answer (score 7):

While your [`Operator.check(...)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.check) method returns True the popup will redraw.

Simple `return True` method used in [`bpy.types.Operator` Dialog Box](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Operator.html#dialog-box) example.  Setting the boolean prop, `my_bool`,  to True reveals more in draw method.

```
import bpy


class DialogOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.dialog_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Dialog Operator"

    my_float = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Some Floating Point")
    my_bool = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Toggle Option")
    my_string = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="String Value")

    def execute(self, context):
        message = "Popup Values: %f, %d, '%s'" % \
            (self.my_float, self.my_bool, self.my_string)
        self.report({'INFO'}, message)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def check(self, context):
        return True

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, "my_bool")
        if self.my_bool:
            layout.label("It's TRUE")
            layout.prop(self, "my_string")

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)


bpy.utils.register_class(DialogOperator)

# test call
bpy.ops.object.dialog_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Comment: I've tested the example. It might work in other versions of blender, but in my version (version 2.76b from the Ubuntu repositories) it doesn't. I've added two print-calls at the beginning of `check()` and `draw()`. It results in this output: `draw \n check \n check \n check \n ...`. So the draw-function is called once at the invocation but not after a change. The check-function is called every time.

Comment: Don't have 2.76b to check against.  On 2.78 (ubuntu) I get "draw" (when invoked) then "check draw" each time the `my_bool` property is (un)checked.  Why not upgrade to a later version of blender. (ie don't rely on the very very slooooooooow to upgrade ubuntu repos)

Comment: I'm writing an addon in context of my master-thesis. It has to be able to run on different often used versions of blender (like the one of the Ubuntu repositories). That's my reason for using this version. An update to a newer version isn't a real solution for this specific problem cause if this addon is used by an user on another version of blender it still will misbehave. Mybe i'll have to use a workaround. Later i'll check the addon using some different blender versions.

Comment: Operator.check, what a cool feature!